# DRF - How to get a single item from a QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to get objects with the `pk` I send through request but I want only one item from the `queryset`.

I want `BatchLog` objects that their `batch_id` is same as the `pk` and my query returns multiple items within that query. I just want one of them and it doesn't matter which one it is.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"])
```

It returns `QuerySet<[BatchLog, BatchLog]>` but I need `QuerySet<BatchLog>`

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: A `QuerySet` is always a *collection* of items. It can be a single item, so `QuerySet<[BatchLog]>`, but not a `QuerySet` that wraps a single item.

Comment: isn't there a way to get `QuerySet` that wraps a single item?

Comment: :it can wrap a sible element, but in a collection, not as "outer structure".

Comment: Why the need for a `query_set()`? The `get_object()` method would be better suited for a single object in a DRF ViewSet.

Comment: @MichaelLindsay yes you are right! but I need to return `get_object_or_404` and it is giving me `MultipleObjectsReturned` error. I am not able to get latest object there.

Comment: @BurakAkyalçın: well the question is more I think if a "detailview" is appropriate. Normally it only makes sense to return details of an item, if we can (easily) reference a single object. By just returning "a random one", it looks like "shoehorning" something in a detailview that is essentially not a detailview.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know there are some problems on relations but I am not able to fix it right now, all I need is to get a random item from that query :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just get the first one.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.kwargs["pk"]).first()

def get_object(self):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    return get_object_or_404(queryset)
```

Comment: That returns BatchLog but I need QuerySet<BatchLog>

Answer (score 1):

You can *slice* the queryset such that it limits the number of results to one, so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return BatchLog.objects.filter(batch_id=self.kwargs['pk'])[:1]
```

If the filter thus matches multiple records, it will return a `QuerySet` that will contain one of these records, this is not per se the first/last one edited/created, this can be different each time you make a query.

If there are no items that match the filter, then this will be an empty `QuerySet`.

If you make use of `filter_backend`s, then the above will not work, therefore it is better *not* to do this at the `get_querset`, but slice the result of `filter_queryset`:

```
class MyListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    # …

    def filter_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().filter_queryset(*args, **kwargs)[:1]
```

Comment: I get an error after trying this
AssertionError: Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken.

Comment: and this returns QuerySet<[BatchLog]> maybe that is the issue

Comment: @BurakAkyalçın: that is because the DRF will use the result on `filter_queryset` call that Django makes. Can you share the full view?